# SEO implications of assigning a new domain to a multisite subdomain

Tags: multisite, seo

I run Wordpress in Network mode (subdomain), and I have built up a good page rank for one of my subdomain sites.

If I register a proper domain name for my network subdomain site, and use the domain mapping plugin to take it from a subdomain of the first site, to being a new domain, does Wordpress do a 301 redirect from the subdomain of the first site to my new domain?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you asked the support of the domain mapping plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "Domain Mapping" section of the WordPress MU Domain Mapping plugin (found under Settings in Network Admin), there is a check box to turn on and off the "Permanent Redirect", which is a 301 permanent redirect.  Turning it off effects a 302 temporary redirect.